# Use Whatsapp HREF on WebView Android

Tags: android, webview

i have a question about using whatsapp button on my mobile version website. I already create a webview appliaction and someone in stackoverflow already helped me to solve my previous issue

[Implement Back Button on WebView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372826/implement-back-button-on-webview-android)

I wanna know how to implement the whatsapp to be opened correctly from the webview. I already tried the `intent` method and whatsapp href but still no luck. I still facing an error

`net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

both on `intent` and normal whatsapp href. Any help would be appreciate. Thank you

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693263/android-webview-err-unknown-url-scheme.) post for your question.

Comment: Tried that already but still give me the same error